# Chemical equation to represent the hydrogen peroxide scavenging experiment, used to determine antioxidant ability of tea

Tags: organic-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I am currently investigating the antioxidant ability of tea using hydrogen peroxide scavenging. Basically, I will look at absorbance of the tea samples with and without the addition of hydrogen peroxide at 230nm using a UV-Vis spectrophotometer and the difference between both is the amount of antioxidants which were able to reduce the hydrogen peroxide. However, although I've been looking theough many papers, none show me the chemical equation representing this reaction. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Is this a standard analysis?!? // Your proposed experiment seems to have problems. (1) Tea has a mixture of chromophores, thus there is no specific reaction. (2) Why do you think that the chromophores in tea are the only compounds capable of reducing hydrogen peroxide? (3) Why would all  chromophores have the same molar absorptivity at 230nm?

Answer (score 1):

I start by quoting [a source](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2013.0901) (which also goes into great detail on explaining the underlying mechanism of chromophores excitation):

> Photosynthesis is initiated by the absorption of light by the chromophores, which excites the molecules from the ground state to an electronic excited state.

So, simply:

$\ce{Chromophores + hv -> *[Chromophores] -> [Chromophores](e-,h+)}$

with the creation of an electron and an electron hole. Now, absence the H2O2, the action of the electron-hole on OH- on water creates an hydroxyl radical:

$\ce{OH- + h+ -> .OH }$

Also, in the further presence of H2O2, a path to the so-called one-electron reduction of hydrogen peroxide from the action of a formed electron (e-) on H2O2, resulting in an additional hydroxyl radical:

$\ce{H2O2 + e- (aq) -> .OH (aq) + OH- (aq) }$

Now, as the tea acts acts as a radical scavenger, it reacts with the hydroxyl radical usually via an H atom extraction reaction forming water. For example:

$\ce{RH + .OH -> .R + H2O}$

The hydroxyl radical continues to attack the chromophores until there is just simple colorless products like CO2 and H2O. In time, the tea solution becomes colorless.

Now, in the combined chromophores and H2O2 experiment, the UV absorbance by tea solution should measurably display more decline with time due to the increased hydroxyl radical concentration.